Problems when listing files with an empty space in the name in a directory using bash
I wanted to have a list of all files inside a directory, because later I am gonna use their names in the code.
I used this code
path="directory"
files=($(ls "$path"))
echo "${#files[@]}"
echo "${files[@]}"

Inside the directory I have only one file "file 0".
The problem is that the empty space is interpreted as a separation between 2 files.
So it prints 2 elements: "file" and "0", as they were 2 different files in the directory.
I couldn't find any question similar to mine.
Bash version:
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release
Linux mint 21.1

Don't parse ls -- ls is for displaying lists of files to a user, not for getting lists of them in a script. Use wildcards and/or find to get lists of files, stat to get their properties.

See Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3)) and Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1).

Don't use ls. Use wildcards that are expanded directly by the shell:
path="directory"
files=("$path"/*)


If you want just the filenames (not including the path prefix), you can remove the path part with "${files[@]##*/}". To remove them from the array, use files=("${files[@]##*/}").
